# DataSet and DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

What is dataset and datatable?
How both of them are related to each other.
And what are the uses of it.

I also want to know how to create a dataset manually and display the data in the web page using c sharp.

As i am newbie to .net and c sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data set is a collection of data tables and the relationships between them. It normally represents a set of database tables and the relationships (foreign keys) between them. See [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) on MSDN.

A data table is usually a representation of a database table, in memory. See [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) on MSDN.

The uses are that you do not need to go to the database every time you want to lookup a value.

---

The rest of your question is rather broad and not really answerable, as there are many ways to create a dataset in memory. You need to be much more specific regarding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't think that is the use case of a DataSet/DataTable. They are useful when you need the structure of multiple tables, want to read and write to the in memory data, want to traverse the data backwards as well as forwards etc.

Comment: @BenCr - In the .NET world, this is the _main_ use case for these types.

Comment: I live in the .NET world (ASP.NET, Silverlight, WCF) and always thought that the _main_ use of DataTables was by inexperienced developers who didn't know the associated costs and alternative options for getting data from the DB. DataTables IMO are nice for MS demos and tutorials but not good for **much** in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

A DataSet is an in memory representation of data,It containing one or more DataTables.
A DataTable is an in-memory representation of data, typically retrieved from a database or XML source.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, a DataSet is a collection of DataTables and the Relations between tables.

A DataTable is an object that represents a table of data similar to a database table.

If I were you I'd avoid the use of DataSets and DataTables as they are fairly heavyweight objects and for simple display you don't need any of the extra features that they provide.

Google for information about DataReaders and maybe DataReaders vs DataTables